# Помогите понять механизм контейнера Dependency Injection

Tags: php, dependency-injection

Все понятно кроме геттера класса DI: что это?

```
return $this->storage[$key]($this);
```

var_dump() показывает что возвращается экземпляр класса Author .. но КАК?
я понимаю запись как: вернуть значение из массива $this->storage по ключу из переменной $key

но **почему там после ключа массива круглые скобки?**
значение по ключу массива $this->storage - анонимная функция
и насколько я понимаю $this - это указатель на текущий экземпляр класса DI

помогите понять как это все работает :/ **почему возвращает объект класса Author??**

```
<?php

class DI {
    protected $storage = [];

    function __set($key, $value) {
        $this->storage[$key] = $value;
    }

    function __get($key) {
        return $this->storage[$key]($this);
    }
}

class Author {
    private $name;

    public function __construct($name) {
        $this->name = $name;
    }

    public function getName() {
        return $this->name;
    }
}

class Question {
    private $author;
    private $question;

    public function __construct($question, $di) {
        $this->author = $di->author;
        $this->question = $question;
    }

    public function getAuthor() {
        return $this->author;
    }

    public function getQuestion() {
        return $this->question;
    }
}

$di = new DI();
$di->author = function() { return new Author('Dima'); };
$question = new Question('What time is it?', $di);
echo $question->getAuthor()->getName() . ': ' . $question->getQuestion(); // Dima: What time is it?

?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ну вы же сами себе уже ответили. По ключу в массиве находится анонимная функция, которая затем вызывается (те самые круглые скобки) - и создает Author, который затем и возвращается.

Comment: хорошо, но меня смутило $this return $this->storage[$key]($this);, почему не return $this->storage[$key]();?

Comment: для меня просто неожиданно что функцию можно так запускать на выполнение. я еще понимаю functionName() или $varOfFunctionName() .. но тут получается кодАнонФункции() да еще и объект класса DI в параметре передается..